# Sitecore Graph QL Search getting unknown argument "FieldsEqual"

Tags: content-search, graphql, sxa-jss

I am trying to execute search on Graph QL. When I try "FieldsEqual" query, I am getting unknown argument in "Query.Search".
Any help to overcome this issue will be highly appreciated.
SC Version is 10.3
[image]

Comment: Are you only having issues with this query or also other queries?
What version of Sitecore are you connected with? Some examples of GraphQL queries you can find here:
https://developers.sitecore.com/trials/jss-connected-demo/exploring-code/graphql Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through your screenshot it seems that you haven't added closing parentheses( `)` ).

Try out this query hope this helps

```
{
  search(
    fieldsEqual:[{name:"title", value:"Si*" }] rootItem:"/sitecore/content"
        ) {
    results {
      items {
        item {
          id
          name
          path
          url
          field(name  : "title") {
           title: value
          }
        }
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

We by default have 3 endpoints for graphql

1. Master --> `https://<instance>/sitecore/api/graph/items/master`
2. Web --> `https://<instance>/sitecore/api/graph/items/web`
3. Edge --> `https://{host-name}/sitecore/api/graph/edge?sc_apikey={GUID}`

As per your comment you are using edge endpoint and you are using `fieldsEqual` this doesn't exisit for edge endpoint check the schema for edge endpoint
`fieldsEqual` exist for master and web endpoint , so now if you try to change your gql endpoint and execute the query you will see the results.

use this endpoint URL and verify if it works--> `https://<instance>/sitecore/api/graph/items/master/ui?sc_apikey={}`

Refer the screenshots of schema from master and edge endpoint for more clarity.

Master :

[image]

Edge :

[image]

Comment: Hi Manoj, I tried the same code in your comment but the result was the same.

Comment: Which GraphQL Endpoint are you using can you confirm the graphql playground url here ?

Comment: Manoj - https://{host-name}/sitecore/api/graph/edge?sc_apikey={GUID} is the playground url format

Comment: @SyleshJL I have updated the answer based on your comment try changing your endpoint to master/web to use FiedlEquals property, for more details refer the answer

Comment: Thanks Manoj for your detailed info. It worked